# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest, "Form" Where is the "form"?

Tags: powershell

I have been dealing with Powershell about a month. I am pretty new to coding and Powershell.

I googled how to use Invoke-WebRequest

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx

or

https://gist.github.com/haraldfianbakken/32d5ac624c842a766df3

I have tried to exact same thing with both links.

so I made a script.

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest "https://idp.appery.io/idp/" -SessionVariable ws;

$r|Get-Member
```

It echoed out

```
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                     
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()                                                  
GetType           Method     type GetType()                                                     
ToString          Method     string ToString()                                                  
BaseResponse      Property   System.Net.WebResponse BaseResponse {get;set;}                     
Content           Property   byte[] Content {get;}                                              
Headers           Property   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] Headers {get;}
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;}                                           
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}                                       
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}                     
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}                                              
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}
```

According these sites, It supposed to have a Form.

so I can go like this

$

```
r=Invoke-WebRequest http://www.facebook.com/login.php -SessionVariable fb

# Use the session variable that you created in Example 1. Output displays values for Headers, Cookies, Credentials, etc. 

$fb

# Gets the first form in the Forms property of the HTTP response object in the $r variable, and saves it in the $form variable. 

$form = $r.Forms[0]

# Pipes the form properties that are stored in the $forms variable into the Format-List cmdlet, to display those properties in a list. 

$form | Format-List

# Displays the keys and values in the hash table (dictionary) object in the Fields property of the form.

$form.fields

# The next two commands populate the values of the "email" and "pass" keys of the hash table in the Fields property of the form. Of course, you can replace the email and password with values that you want to use. 

$form.Fields["email"] = "User01@Fabrikam.com"
$form.Fields["pass"] = "P@ssw0rd"
```

I would like to go exact the same path with above code,but this, I do not see the "Form" on https://idp.appery.io/idp/, when i see the website, there is forms which I can type my credentials, but when I did $r|gm, the "Form" does not showing up.

Are any reasons not showing up?

Is there another way to put my credential, so I can do exact same things like both site?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I get Forms in my object.  Per the documentation, you're only going to get what's there.

Here's when I try google:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri google.com | gm


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

Name              MemberType Definition                                                                 
----              ---------- ----------                                                                 
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                             
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()                                                          
GetType           Method     type GetType()                                                             
ToString          Method     string ToString()                                                          
AllElements       Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection AllElements {get;}
BaseResponse      Property   System.Net.WebResponse BaseResponse {get;set;}                             
Content           Property   string Content {get;}                                                      
Forms             Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormObjectCollection Forms {get;}            
Headers           Property   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] Headers {get;}        
Images            Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Images {get;}     
InputFields       Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection InputFields {get;}
Links             Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Links {get;}      
ParsedHtml        Property   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 ParsedHtml {get;}                                    
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;}                                                   
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}                                               
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}                             
Scripts           Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Scripts {get;}    
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}                                                      
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}
```

When I try the site you're talking about, I don't even get an HtmlWebResponse object back.

In this case, it might be good to try the automation you're after with IE automation instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I try to do like this, now $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://idp.appery.io/idp/")   I hope this is what you are talking about